# Get Date in SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, date

In my code, I have to select the start date and end date for the SQL query to run. I have to obtain the start and end date from a date picker for the value to be display. Below is my code: Any ideas.?

```
include 'DBController.php';

$db_handle = new DBController();
$start_date = $_GET['start_date'];
$end_date  = $_GET['end_date'];

$productResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT outlets.outletname,outlets.barcode,invoiceissued.invoiceno,invoiceissued.total_amount,invoiceissued.VATAmount,invoiceissued.date_created,outlets.businessregistrationno,outlets.vat 
FROM `invoiceissued` , outlets 
WHERE invoiceissued.outletid = outlets.outletsid and `date_created` 
BETWEEN ('".$start_date."') AND ('".$end_date."')");

<body>
     Start date : <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date"/>
                    End date : <input type="date" id="end_date" 
      name="end_date" />   
</body>
```

Comment: how have you stored the dates in the DB?

Comment: What is your actual question? And you should use prepared statements. Right now you're vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: date format is 2019-07-01  My question is in my form i have to select the start and end date GET the values so that the value is inserted in the $start_date and run the query

Comment: Will is giving you a hint with his question, depening on how the dates are stored in your DB you should format $start_date/$end_date

Comment: the value store is 2019-07-06 but want that the value enter in the textbox is POSTed in the variable $start_date and $end_date and run the sql query

Comment: You need to ensure your date posted matches your data in your date column(s).  If it doesn't you will need to format the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume:

```
 $start_date = $_GET['start_date']; // is string - 2018-03-15
 $end_date  = $_GET['end_date']; // is string -2018-03-20
```

You'll need to do something like :

```
$start_date = strtotime($_GET['start_date']);
$formatedStartDate = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $start_date);// or whatever format you need

$end_date = strtotime($_GET['end_date']); 
$formatedEndDate = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $end_date);// or whatever format you need
```

1rst you convert strings to timestamps with [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then you format this timestamps with the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split it into 2 parts

1. Display the date picker in HTML
2. Get the **start date** & **end date** from date picker and then make an ajax call to run your sql query